# How to enable full page swiping in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I make swipe available in the middle of the screen on the VIewPager? Like on the app store, you can swipe anywhere to go to the next tab! Currently that happens only when I swipe from the extreme corner of the screen(Bezel Swipe)

MY code:

```
public class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {

ViewPager viewPager;
SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
ArrayList<String> tabs;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

    tabs = new ArrayList<String>();
    tabs.add("Image");
    tabs.add("Something Else");
    tabs.add("Some Long Title");
    tabs.add("Songs");
    tabs.add("Off The Page!");

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new VPAdapterHelper());

    slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingTabs);
    slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
}

public class VPAdapterHelper extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
        container.addView(view);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.VP_ListView);
        // TODO set different adapters for different tabs
        listView.setAdapter(new AdapterHelper(context));

        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return obj == view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

swipe_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<com.nischal.test.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/slidingTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/VP_ListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be able to swipe to different tabs from anywhere on the page.
I tried overriding the DragListner of the container and dispatched a draylistner to the viewpage, but did not help!

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: A `ViewPager` swipe can be initiated pretty much anywhere. In order to successfully swipe, you will need to initiate the swipe on the opposite half of the screen (e.g., start finger on left half and swipe right). See this sample project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Fragments

Comment: okay! i almost completely have the same code, but mine swipes only from the bezel! i think the problem in my project is that the listview detects the swipe rather than the viewpager!

Comment: i put up a few log statements and i was right, the listview detects the swipes(touches) and not the viewpager! the listview has a margin of 8dp, so only 8dp from the bezel is where the viewpager sees the swipes. any fix?

Comment: I'm sure there's a solution, as there are plenty of apps using `ListView` in a `ViewPager` page, but I don't have any ideas off the top of my head.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I'll Google for an open source app.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question. The problem seems to be in the listview item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="1dip"
android:paddingBottom="1dip"
android:paddingStart="8dip"
android:paddingEnd="8dip">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/CL_imageView"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CL_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here, the textview gravity tag was set to center, which for some reason caused the whole problem. removed the gravity tag and problem solved!

Comment: thanks for the answer..i also face same problem..now solved thanks..again